# Get monitor number widget is on in gtk 2

Tags: c, gtk

So there is an application I would like to patch. It uses `GtkWidget` as its topmost container. I would like to do what follows, check number of screens, if it is >2 then check the width of the screen the app is executed on (focus is on screen). I could use `Xinerama` but first I would like to try native Gtk things. What I do is:

```
  num_monitors = gdk_screen_get_n_monitors (screen);
```

Then I found a function `gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_window(screen, ?window?)` but it takes screen and GtkWindow as its argument. Unfortunately I have no window, only widget. I tried to                                                                                                                       get window by `gtk_widget_get_parent_window(widget)` or `gtk_widget_get_window(widget)` these always result in giving me `GDK_IS_WINDOW (widget)` failed. On the other hand `gtk_widget_get_has_window(window)` returns 1.

How can I determine screen the app was run on ? I need it to set width hints right.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably failing to get the window because the widget isn't realized and/or mapped, yet. You'll get `NULL` from `gtk_widget_get_window()` if it isn't.

The return value from `gtk_widget_get_has_window()` is probably static; a particular class of widget either always has a window, or never has one.

Try forcing the widget to be realized with [`gtk_widget_realize()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-realize), before extracting the window. If that fails, also try to map it.

You might want to investigate this from the other end, i.e. decide which screen you want/expect the widget to use, and look up that screen's info, without starting from the widget itself.

Comment: I tried realize but did not help.   gtk_widget_realize(widget);                     
  i = gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_window(screen, widget->window);t

Answer (score 0):

The window must be actually shown before the function returns you the correct screen the window resides on. This makes your window manager apply its placement policy. To ensure the widget is shown you can use `gtk_main_iteration()`, calling it until there are no more pending events.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget*const widget=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show(widget);
    while(gtk_events_pending())
        gtk_main_iteration();

    GdkWindow*const window=gtk_widget_get_window(widget);
    GdkScreen*const screen=gdk_window_get_screen(window);
    const int monitor=gdk_screen_get_monitor_at_window(screen,window);
    printf("Monitor number: %d\n",monitor);
}
```